# Postgres with SSL in Docker: It takes too long to connect from psql

Tags: postgresql, docker, ssl

I'm running the official Postgres image in Docker with self-signed SSL certificates. Here is my docker-compose definition:

```
  pg13:
    image: postgres:13
    command: >
      -E
    hostname: postgres
    ports:
      - "10130:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./PGDATA:/PGDATA
      - ./.docker/postgres/initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./certs/server.crt:/var/lib/postgresql/server.crt
      - ./certs/server.key:/var/lib/postgresql/server.key
      - ./certs/root.crt:/var/lib/postgresql/root.crt
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/PGDATA
      - POSTGRES_DB=chesco
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=chesco
      - POSTGRES_USER=chesco
```

postgresql.conf

```
ssl=on
ssl_cert_file='/var/lib/postgresql/server.crt'
ssl_key_file='/var/lib/postgresql/server.key'
ssl_ca_file='/var/lib/postgresql/root.crt'
```

pg_hba.conf

```
hostssl all all all cert
```

Now that having all of that, I'm trying to reach the database with psql from my host machine:

```
psql "host=localhost dbname=chesco user=chesco port=10130 \
  sslmode=verify-full \
  sslcert=/Users/ivan/work/pg/certs/client.crt \
  sslkey=/Users/ivan/work/pg/certs/client.key \
  sslrootcert=/Users/ivan/work/pg/certs/root.crt"
```

The problem is, it takes up to 1-2 minutes to connect! When I do the same with a local instance of Postgres, it connects immediately (I only change the port number). What is wrong here?

MacOS v12.3.1 M1, Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701

The certificates were generated using this gist: https://gist.github.com/achesco/b893fb55b90651cf5f4cc803b78e19fd

Comment: You should debug that with a tool like Wireshark. Perhaps something in the network is too slow. At least you'd figure out where the time is spent, and you can dig deeper there.

Comment: Or, just `strace -ttt -T` your psql call and see what it is doing for that length of time.